# Where is an error in my deduction? (question about martingales)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

Suppose we have a filtration $\{\mathcal{F_{t}},t\geq 0\}$ and a stochastic process $\{ X_{t},t\geq 0\}$ which is adapted to this filtration and also integrable. All we need for this process to be a martingale is to hold $ E[X_{t} | \mathcal{F_{s}} ] = X_{s}$ for every $t > s$. But suppose we take a trivial filtration i.e. $\mathcal{F_{t}}=\mathcal{F}$ for every $t\geq 0$ 
where $\mathcal{F}$ is some sigma-algebra in our probability space. Then obviously $ E[X_{t} | \mathcal{F_{s}} ] = X_{t}$ for every $t > s$ which breaks our martingale property. So adaptability and integrability for $\{ X_{t},t\geq 0\}$ and $ E[X_{t} | \mathcal{F_{s}} ] = X_{s}$ is not enough to be a martingale? Do we need some extra assumtions concerning $\{\mathcal{F_{t}},t\geq 0\}$?

Comment: A martingale is a martingale always with respect to a filtration. A process that is a martingale with respect to one filtration may not be a martingale with respect to another filtration.

Comment: @AddSup I mean adaptability to a trivial filtration which I described in the question, the fact that X is adaptable to such filtration makes this process somehow trivial as well or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\left(X_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\left(\mathcal F_t\right)_{t\geqslant 0}$ where $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F$ for all $t$.

The condition of adaptedness implies that for all $t$, $X_t$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable.

The condition $\mathbb E\left[X_t\mid\mathcal F_s\right]=X_s$ for $0\leqslant s\lt t$ reads therefore $X_s=\mathbb E\left[X_t\mid\mathcal F\right]=X_t$, since $X_t$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable hence $X_t=X_0$ for all $t$.

Comment: So such a process would be stationary?

Comment: It would be even "constant", in sense that $X_t$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: So if we take some fancy combination of Wiener process (e.g. $\frac{1}{3}W_{t}^3-tW_{t}$ as $X_{t}$) and say that it is adapted to some arbitrary filtration then it's not gonna be a martingale in general because of this possibility of taking "trivial filtration"? Even though martingale property seems to work here.

Comment: This fancy combination could be a martingale, but for an other filtration.